# Why are all the methods in Assembly-CSharp.dll empty?

Tags: c#, il2cpp, dnspy

> I have recently decompiled the **GameAssembly.dll** from Among Us using *Il2CppDumper-v6.7.6*

My problem is that while i have the file **Assembly-CSharp.dll** open with *dnSpy*, all of the methods/functions are empty, as shown below,

[image]

**Does anyone know how i can fix this and see the methods/functions?**

Answer (score 0):

That`s how IL2Cpp works, you are not able to get readable C# code anymore even if you will use dumper for that, idk may be there is a something that could do that, I'm not a pro at this.

Probably also `Among Us` using their custom protector as additional, that invokes methods by `token/address`, seems to mechanic as call to calli.